# How can I fix tall ket notation?

Tags: brackets, physics

I have been struggling with a tall ket symbol when I insert the letter `b` compared to the letter `a`. My problem is how I can make the ket notation for the letter `b` the same size as the letter `a`. I also tried to put `\small`, but it did not work at all.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are using the `physics` package, I presume?

Comment: The `physics` package has several shortcomings and this one of them and not the least. The syntax is often very awkward and the typesetting very low quality.

Comment: @Vincent yes! I used the ``physics``  package!

Comment: `physics` has starred versions of `\ket` and `\bra` for this purpose. Just use `\ket*`.

Comment: Related: *[bra–ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation)* (AKA Dirac notation). Sample: *[How it is possible that a ket precedes a bra in a matrix expression?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665181/how-it-is-possible-that-a-ket-precedes-a-bra-in-a-matrix-expression)*

Answer (score 6):

The problem you've run into arises because the `physics` package defines `\ket` to have autosizing delimiters.

- A brute-force solution consists of `\smash`-ing the term `\hat{b}`. It's not even a foolproof solution, as there could be adverse (typographical) consequences to having `\smash`ed the tall term `\hat{b}`.
- A more elegant solution would be to wean yourself off the autosizing habits of the `physics` package, say by employing the `mathtools` package to create an alternate definition of `\ket` -- `\altket` -- that doesn't autosize the delimiters by default. (To go back to autosizing, just use `\altket*`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}   % for '\ket' macro
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\altket}{\vert}{\rangle}

\begin{document}
$\ket{\hat{a}_{\tau}}$ $\ket{\hat{b}_{\sigma}}$ --- bad

\bigskip
$\ket{\hat{a}_{\tau}}$ $\ket{\smash{\hat{b}}_{\sigma}}$  --- brute-force solution

\bigskip
$\altket{\hat{a}_{\tau}}$ $\altket{\hat{b}_{\sigma}}$ --- elegant solution

\bigskip
$\altket*{\hat{a}_{\tau}}$ $\altket*{\hat{b}_{\sigma}}$ --- back to bad

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I understand what should I do finally!

Comment: `\ket*` in `physics` won't do the resize.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the starred version, which prevents resizing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

Here is $\ket*{\hat{a}_{\tau}}$ and $\ket*{{\hat{b}}_{\sigma}}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is much quicker!